# Creating a list of strings where each string, is a key, to a list of tuples (as value), in java

Tags: java, list, data-structures, dictionary, hashmap

How can I create a list of strings where each string points to a list of tuples; In other words each string is a key to a list of tuples (as value)?

Each tuple should be of the form :

```
List<String> pref, where each element of the list pref (say pref_i):
pref1 --> {(T1:10),(T2:13), T3:3),...}
pref2 --> {(T1:7), (T4:3), (T5:1),...}
pref3 --> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me you want a `Map`, depending on the type of your tuple (assuming a String here):

```
Map<String, List<String>> prefs = new HashMap<String, List<String>>;
```

You can have your tuples be of any type, I used a String for convenience.

If your tuples are better represented though a `Set` or `Map`, change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

MultiMap to the rescue!

There is no such thing as touples in java, unless you simulate them.
A multimap is like having a Map, where key is String and Value is an Array of elements

[MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a HashMap of HashMap ? The first HashMap to use your string keys and the second one to your tuples.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Hope this helps ! Bye !

Answer (score 0):

You cal also use List.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    public class TestArrayList {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<String> tempList=new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> temp1=new ArrayList<String>();
            temp1.add(0, "a");
            temp1.add(1, "b");
            List<String> temp2=new ArrayList<String>();
            temp2.add(0, "c");
            temp2.add(1, "d");
            List<String> temp3=new ArrayList<String>();
            temp3.add(0, "e");
            temp3.add(1, "f");
            tempList.addAll(0, temp1);
            tempList.addAll(1, temp2);
            tempList.addAll(1, temp3);

            for(int i=0;i<tempList.size();i++){
                System.out.println(">>"+tempList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```